# java socket server hosting

Tags: hosting, java-server

I am creating an android client app connected to a Java server using sockets. At the moment I am working both on my pc. How can I upload my Java server to an online server so I can set my app to friends and test it?

I used OpenShift but could figure our how and if I can use it for what I want.
Also I looked at Amazon ec2, but they need credit card information, something that I would prefer not sharing for this.

Is there any way I can do this for free?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a computer able to connect to the internet, and that can run 24/7. Then run your server on that computer, assume you run it on port 8080. Make sure that your host computer's IP address is it to static, otherwise DHCP will give it a different IP every time it connects to the router.

To allow your friends to connect, unless if they're on the same LAN as your host, you will need to port forward port 80 -> ComputerIP:8080 on your router. Once that's done, you will need to retrieve your router's global IPv4 address from it's configuration page and then send that to your friends.

If they're on the same LAN as your host, then you can just give them the IP address of your host computer.

If you port forwarded your server and you would like to get a host name, like stackoverflow.com, you're going to need to buy that from whoever owns the host name you would like to use. I don't know many details about how to update the DNS servers though.

If your server is local and you would like a host name, then just go onto your router configurations page and tell it to automatically assign each computer the default gateway as the primary DNS and then add a mapping in the router's DNS settings to map the host name to your computer's local IPv4 address. Note that not all routers support this feature.

Edit: You'll also need a good bandwidth to support multiple simultaneous connections.